Follow-up question to: How do I add a number (or index value) to the middle of a filename stored in a variable in BASH?
I have a related question to my original post a couple of months ago:
Suppose in the terminal window I entered the following;
doc_path="/Users/joeblogs/My Files/Documents/"

file3_L="$doc_path/txt/Testfile.txt"

echo $file3_L

which outputs:
/Users/joeblogs/My Files/Documents/txt/Testfile.txt

and then I enter;
n=3

left="file${n}_L"

echo $left

which outputs:
file3_L

Issue:
I can't seem to get the same output as I get from using echo $file3_L by instead using the value of $left - is there something I am missing in terms of the bash syntax / brace expansion?
What I would like to get (by using $left in some way) is:
/Users/joeblogs/My Files/Documents/txt/Testfile.txt 

This will help with my original goal(s).
Any help/advice is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Your title should describe this question. Referring to the previous question is not very meaningful.

Why not just use an array instead of creating variables with numbers in them?

It's almost always better to use arrays for things like this. Just use file_L[3]="$doc_path/txt/Testfile.txt" to set array elements, then e.g. echo "${file_L[3]}" to get values from the array.

It goes back to my original post of having 15 pairs of variables, each with an index number, and the contents of the variables is a path to a text file (one for the source and one for the backup copy) to be used with the diff command.  And then using a loop for the index instead of having 15 separate diff command statements in the bash script.  I kind of see what you are saying though - have 2 arrays with 15 elements in each - one array for the left file locations and the other for the right file locations?

From Shell Parameter Expansion:

If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of indirection. Bash uses the value formed by expanding the rest of parameter as the new parameter; this is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the expansion, rather than the expansion of the original parameter. This is known as indirect expansion.
The value is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. If parameter is a nameref, this expands to the name of the variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the complete indirect expansion. The exceptions to this are the expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below (follow the link for more). The exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to introduce indirection.

This gives:
echo "${!left}"


Exactly what I was looking for and thanks for the reference info.

@TheEngineer Great, you're welcome!
